# cant get next page button to toggle off on last page

Tags: actionscript-3, debugging, events, toggle, flash-cs5

in my program the user can click on a key for helpful information that is multipaged. when he hits next it goes to the next page and the previous button shows. Im trying to get it to toggle off the next button on the last page and previous button the the first page.

other info:
KeyPage = the pages. frame 1 is blank. 2 is page 1 and 3 is page 2.
keyPageFrame = variable i use to track the current keyPage. 0 is frame 1, 1 is frame 2 and 2 is frame 3
keyButtonPrev = previous button. frame 1 is off 2 is showing and 3 is hover
keyButtonNext = same as above but the next button

```
//seccessfully toggles keyPage and previuos and next buttons regardless of page 
function KeyButtonFunction(e:Event):void
{
    if (keyPageFrame==0)
        {KeyPage.gotoAndStop(2); keyPageFrame=2; keyButtonNext.gotoAndStop(2);}
    else
        {KeyPage.gotoAndStop(1); keyPageFrame=0; keyButtonNext.gotoAndStop(1); keyButtonPrev.gotoAndStop(1)}
}
```

when the user clicks the next button the following function runs. it runs seccessfully except for the fact that the next button wont go to frame 1

```
function KeyButtonNextFunction(e:Event):void
{
    keyButtonPrev.gotoAndStop(2)
    KeyPage.gotoAndStop(keyPageFrame+1);
    keyPageFrame=keyPageFrame+1;
}
```

Ive tried going to frame 1 in an if statement still doesnt work. I tried calling another function in the function. the function calls but will not go to frame and i tried a while statement out side of function and well that...completely crashes flash before it loads. for my statements ive been using keyPageFrame in the conditions. they been validating so thats not the problem. also all my objects are movie clips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the 'enabled' property of the button.  A quick and dirty way of using it would be to put  the actionscript below in each frame:

```
keyButtonNext.enabled = true; //this would be false obviously in the last frame
keyButtonPrev.enabled = true; //and this would be false in the first frame
```

You could also just detect the current frame and set the the property based on that.

```
switch (currentFrame)
{
case 2:
keyButtonNext.enabled = true;
keyButtonPrev.enabled = false;
break;
case 3:
keyButtonNext.enabled = true;
keyButtonPrev.enabled = true;
case 4:
keyButtonNext.enabled = false;
keyButtonPrev.enabled = true;
break;
default:
trace ("I have no idea what page you're on")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but unfortunately enabled does not work. I tried it with a few of my instances and it wont work with any of them...strangely with my code it will go away as the keyPage toggles successfully but not when i was going page to page. my guess is you cant click on an instance and tell it to go to another frame?

Comment: With buttons you create, as opposed to the button component, setting enabled to false won't have any visual effect on the button. You just won't be able to click on it. If you want the button to disappear, use `keyButton.visible = false` when you don't want it.

Comment: Looking at your code again, it seems you're doing something a little odd. Flash IDE created buttons have 4 frames:up,over,down,and hit.  There shouldn't be a blank frame. You should use Actionscript to turn the button off, with .visible or .enabled, not jumping the button to a blank frame.  I'd scrap your buttons and code, make proper buttons, add a CLICK event listener, and have the function call nextFrame() or prevFrame(), depending, and use the .visible property to turn off the particular button on the first and last frame.

Comment: correct. my solution would not work. thank you for you mention of the .visable. my objects were done incorectly. my prof showed us only the animation side of flash and i ended up doing a bunch of symbols in symbols which caused great frustration so i rewrote the code using .visable and array of the symbols i need on each page. thank you!